# Always boots to tty1 after uninstalling KDE plasma (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)

Tags: 22.04, kde

I always booted to `tty1` after removing KDE plasma on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, I have logged in to the `tty1`, but I have no idea what should I do after login to `tty1`.

Comment: Why do you want to ask about "How to use Linux?".(tty1 It is just the Linux terminal). Better to stick to KDE.. do `sudo apt install kde-full`. If you have gnome installed, do `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and change to gdm3. If it doesn't appear in the menu try `sudo apt install gdm3`

Answer (score 1):

So you removed the graphical interface, and now you're booting to a terminal. Which graphical interface would you like at boot? If Gnome is already present, you can run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

If not, you have to reinstall the desktop environment. If you were to switch back to the default Gnome desktop, use this command:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

If it gives a `ubuntu-desktop is already the newest version....` then try with the `--reinstall` flag.

```
sudo apt --reinstall install ubuntu-desktop
```

Afterwards, it might be a good idea to run the following to clean up:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: Not required... Just have to do `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` as KDE uses a different suite of applications ( Except LibreOffice and a few more but most of it is the same).

Comment: Plus make sure to remove the unused applications. And if The gnome desktop is not even present, then no need of the `--reinstall` flag.

Comment: I tried to run dpkg reconfigure but it says: dpkg-query: package 'lightdm' is not installed and no info ...

Comment: Then try install (possibly `--reinstall`) of `ubuntu-desktop`..

Comment: Sorry i forgot to install them first

Answer (score 0):

#### Steps to fix tty1 default booting.

Note: The reason why it boots to tty1 (not GUI) is that there is no GUI in your machine. You need to install ubuntu-desktop.

**First Connect to the internet, I use usb tethering**

```
ip adress | grep usb0
sudo dhclient usb0
```

try to ping, for example, ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

**Update and install ubuntu-client**

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y ubuntu-desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that uninstalling KDE also removed lightdm. I didn't realize this until I tried to updated it to select gdm3 and got a message that package lightdm wasn't installed.

Try
sudo apt install lightdm
and select gdm3 when you get to that screen.

I'm booting to the Gnome login screen after doing this.